# Combinar dos tablas en una en laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo dos tablas que prácticamente están duplicadas, por lo que quiero pasar los datos de una a la otra y quedarme solo con una tabla.

Tengo la tabla product con id, code, name, ref_code, y la tabla new_product con id, cod, product_name, fk_code.

Me quiero quedar con la tabla new_product. Para ello le he creado una columna nueva llamada cda_code, donde hay que insertar el ref_code de la tabla products.

Necesito recorrer la tabla prouct e insertar en cda_code el ref_code si coinciden en el nombre o en el puerto. Y si no hay coincidencias, insertar todos los datos.

El fin es quedarme solo con new_product.

Pero no sé como combinar estas tablas, ya que lo único que he visto es hacer un select que me coja datos de ambas pero no guardarlos y conmbinarlo.

Utilizo laravel 7.

Si necesitais algún dato en concreto os edito la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, puedes crear y usar un **seeder** que haga esta tarea para ti, junto con una **migración** que elimine la antigua tabla que ya no se usara, si lo deseas coloca un ejemplo de la lógica que compara tus datos y los inserta y con gusto te ayudo, saludos

Comment: La duda en si no parece relacionada a algún problema con Laravel, dicho lo anterior sería conveniente edites y agregues aquello que hayas intentado y dudas puntuales respecto a ese código, por favor lee [ask]